# What is the impact when Marketing Cloud Connector user password changes?

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect

We have set up Marketing Cloud Connector to integrate Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud. We need to change password for our user that we created in Sales Cloud(having 'Admin' permissions). Will it have any repercussions on our Connector or our active journeys in SFMC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We changed the password of our user in Sales Cloud and faced no issues, hence adding the points here:

1) If Marketing Cloud version is 2.0.8 and above, then changing password will not break the connection.

2) Refreshing password will not impact any existing customer journeys or any other data source within Marketing Cloud.